# Como chamar o evento SelectedIndexChanged de um método

Tags: c#, webforms

Como eu chamo o evento SelectedIndexChanged de uma Dropdownlist em um outro método. Uso WebForm.

Comment: A resposta existe e funciona. Também considere que uma boa prática seria promover todo o código do método do evento pra um novo método. No evento seria feita uma chamada a esse método. E nesse caso específico também, seria chamado esse método em vez do evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seuDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Em realidade o que eu estou tentando é fazer a combo exibir um texto de acordo com a minha pesquisa. Tipo, a pesquisa trouxe o número de um banco, digamos 237, isso equivale a Bradesco S/A em minha combo. Quando eu trouxer esse resultado, gostaria que o texto Bradesco S/A fosse exibido na combo de acordo com o seu value que nesse caso é 237.

Comment: @pnet nesse caso será necessário abrir outra pergunta visto que o que você quer está diferente do que foi perguntado primeiramente.